# Creating Different CSS Layers

Tags: html, css

Hello I am new to css and am in need of some assistance. I am wanting to create 3 layers in CSS for my website so it looks like the picture I have provided below.

[image: Picture Provided]

How would I go about setting this up in CSS? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: You have not provided any kind of markup, and it's difficult to assess your situation as such. Here's a guide on how to create a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just need to know if it's possible to create 3 different containers with the following backgrounds and how I would go about doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: **yes, it is possible**. Then again, without any markup how are we supposed to help? On SO it helps that you come with a specific problem statement showing *what you have tried so far*.

Comment: You should start by learning how to code and then come back with a code that we can look at and fix if there is any problem

Answer (score 3):

You want to learn about the z-index property. But basically, anything you apply `z-index` to needs to have a `position` set... I'm pretty sure `static` doesn't work but `absolute` `relative` & `fixed` all do it. then you can just order them. For example:

```
.div-background{
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
.div-middle{
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
}
.div-front{
  z-index:3;
  position:relative;
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes it makes sense I will have a look into that and see how I go.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add the background img of the pattern to the css
here's an example of the code

```
div {
background: url(../images/purpalt.png) repeat; 
}
```

[http://www.bootply.com/4iBwk4Tmfr][1]

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: black;
  height: 553px;

  }

.container {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    height: 553px;
    width: 960px;
  }

  .image-box {
    background: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      height: 500px;
    }

  footer {
      background: orange;
      height: 190px;


<div class="container-full">

      <div class="jumbotron">

      </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="image-box">
    Image to go here

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>    


</div> <!-- /container full -->
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Have advanced a bit further by making a footer at the bottom of my page. Only problem is it's stuck there and with pages that are longer it won't move. My html code is, <div class="footer">
          <p>
            <div align="left">
              &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo $sitename; ?>
            </div>
   </p>
          </div> and css is .footer {
 background-color: #F6861F;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 190px;
    position: fixed;
}